# Unable to install SVN plugin in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

I am using Jenkins as standalone WebApp (i.e. .WAR file). I am unable however to install Subversion Modules plugin in Jenkins. I have checked all the available plugins but I could not figure out which one is SVN plugin. Could anyone please help me on this issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A search of https://plugins.jenkins.io/ produces the following result [Subversion](https://plugins.jenkins.io/subversion):

> This plugin adds the Subversion support (via SVNKit) to Jenkins. **This plugin is bundled inside jenkins.war**

(emphasis mine)

...

> **Basic Usage**
>
> Once this plugin is installed, you'll see Subversion as one of the options in the SCM section of job configurations.

So you already have the plugin and there are detailed instructions on the [Subversion](https://plugins.jenkins.io/subversion) web page.

Comment: I am unable to see Subversion Modules in Source Code management section when creating a new Item. Also no plugin wtih such a name appears neither in the installed nor in the available plugins.